# Issue with joining dataframes with columns containing '-' in between column names

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to join two dataframes df1 and df2 which have the same column name as "my-name".

```
    final_df=df1.join(df2,df1.my-name=df2.my-name)
```

It gave me an error "Dataframe object has no attribute my". 
I also tried using backticks to escape '-'.It gave me invalid syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use dot notation. Either

```
df1.join(df2, ["my-name"])
```

or

```
df1.join(df2, df1["my-name"] == df2["my-name"])
```